# How to I convert my current react project(webapp) into a mobile app?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, mobile-application

Hey everyone I am new to javascript and react & recently started building apps to learn. The app I created used expo, which was perfect because I could actually see the app on my phone - the second app that I am working on right now is more of a webapp. I can see the app on my localhost, on my web browser. I can also see it on my phones web browser but I want to convert it into a expo-type project where I see it as an actual mobile app & not a web based app. Are there any good documentations for doing this? I have not yet found anything that will help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways you can approach it. ReactJs doesn't give custom approach to convert it into native app but it does give you access to `serviceWorker`using which you can convert your webapp into a `PWA (Progressive Web App)` which is a webapp that you can install in your Android/iOS device even in your desktop.

Another way is to use Native app frameworks that are using WebView technology like Ionic. You can use web components in Ionic to build native mobile apps and Ionic also support ReactJs also.

You can explore these options. I'm sure you will find a way to resolve your problem.